# Change buffer in dialysis?

Tags: chromatography, purification

I have a protein that I purified in PBS buffer, pH 7. I will do dialysis to remove salt and will then further purify the protein with ion exchange chromatography.

I will need to use another buffer (Tris-HCl) with pH 8 in the chromatography, and so my question is: 
Can I change the buffer system for my protein in the dialysis step? Or would you recommend me to use the Tris-HCl buffer from the very start and then just adjust the pH for the chromatography?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tris-HCl works from pH ~7 to ~9. Does the processes upstream of the filtration work with Tris-HCl? See also: diafiltration and buffer exchange.